# Adding wifi SSID and PASSWORD to sdkconfig

Tags: esp32, esp-idf

I'm creating a wifi application using ESP-IDF based on the examples but the example I'm using has options for setting the SSID and PASSWORD under:

> Example Connection Configuration

[image]

when using `idf.py menuconfig` and which are used by `CONFIG_EXAMPLE_WIFI_SSID` and `CONFIG_EXAMPLE_WIFI_PASSWORD` in the code.

I want to set SSID and PASSWORD in my own project without using this in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(EXTRA_COMPONENT_DIRS $ENV{IDF_PATH}/examples/common_components/protocol_examples_common)
```

without the above there isn't a way to define SSID and PASSWORD. They appear in:

> build/config/kconfig_menus.json

but I can't seem to keep this from being overwritten in my own project. `sdkconfig` states it should not be edited.

Is there a best practice for using `idf.py menuconfig`? Or do most people just use `sdkconfig.defaults` and not use `idf.py menuconfig`?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually tracked down the file `Kconfig.projbuild` in the example project via the [build system docs](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html):

> Each component may also include a Kconfig file defining the component
> configuration options that can be set via menuconfig. Some components
> may also include Kconfig.projbuild and project_include.cmake files,
> which are special files for overriding parts of the project.

created my own version and put it in `main` and the options now appear when using `idf.py menuconfig`. Thanks to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGo5PJrYP-o&ab_channel=SIMSIOTDevices).

Answer (score 0):

When we use ESP-IDF example and change config using **idf.py menuconfig** there is one config option **example configuration** that is custom or user's own configuration created by espressif. And we can also make our own configuration like that.
Kconfig.projbuild is used for making our own configuration. for details see below links.

[how-to-add-custom-configuration-in-project-config](https://medium.com/@bhautik.markeye/esp-idf-configuration-how-to-add-custom-configuration-in-project-config-728f81b8d0d8)

[Espressif official doc](https://Project%20Configuration)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33539265)